# Download Image with specific Div via Script

Tags: node.js, bash, perl, scripting, automation

I have a series of URLs that I need to download a single image from for each.

In the markup for each of these pages there is the following

```
<div class="subcolumns product-hero">
        <div class="c60l">
                <img src="Cubes.png" width="300"/> 
        </div>
</div>
```

I need to ideally download the image within the div with a class of product-hero, or save the image src tag.

Is this possible through some kind of automated script? Node/Perl etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) which allows you to load and query webpages in pure javascript (no browser required).

Have a look at [Phantom's DOM Manipulation](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html) for how to access the document, and then you can use vanilla javascript dom queries (such as `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName`) to access the images you need. So your script might look like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            var productHeros = document.getElementsByClassName('product-hero');
            for (var i = 0; i < productHeros.length; i++) {
                var productHeroDiv = productHeros[i];
                var image = productHeroDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
                var source = image.src;
            }
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given list of URLs as argument list:

```
#!/bin/bash
for url in "$@"; do
    img_src=$( curl -s "$url" | \
        xmllint 2>/dev/null --recover --html --xpath \
        'string(//div[contains(@class, 'product-hero')]/img/@src)' - )
    curl -O "$(dirname "$url")/$img_src"
done
```